# Regex capture groups vs. using split on dates, which is better?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

In multiple instances I've found myself needing to capture the "day" part of a date formatted like : `"YYYY/DD/MM"` My question is in whether or not it was a better idea to use a regex with a capturing group vs. just calling split on "/" and just taking the second item in the array?

Functionally I realize that BOTH get the same result.

Memory-wise, I realize that they BOTH use the regex engine under the hood, and that in most cases I'm just discarding the the array after reading the value for day using split.  But technically I do the exact same thing after reading from the `Match` object as well.  I'm looking to see if there's any corner cases and tradeoffs I should be considering that I'm not?  (Besides readability... "split" clearly wins there...)

===EDIT===
API-wise I'm limited to Groovy 1.5.0 for silly legacy reasons.

To clarify edmastermind's solution:

```
def nowCal = Calendar.instance 
def currentDay = nowCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Comment: Noticing the java tag, isn't it feasible to call [DAY_OF_MONTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) to get the "day" part instead of regexing or splitting it out? Or are you going a different direction with this?

Comment: Actually this is probably the cleanest solution I've seen yet.  There are some other good ideas here but you should post yours as an answer.
`def nowCal = Calendar.instance
def currentDay = nowCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy, you can just do:

```
def date = '2012/05/25'

assert 25 == Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', date )[ Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ]
```

For Groovy 1.5.0, this would be (wrapped as a function):

```
int getDay( String date, String format='yyyy/MM/dd' ) {
  Calendar.instance.with {
    time = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( format ).parse( date )
    get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH )
  }
}

def date = '2012/05/25'
assert 25 == getDay( date )
```

Comment: I'm limited to Groovy 1.5.0 where that language feature is missing.  Updated the question with that info.

Comment: @avgvstvs what error do you get? We might be able to work round it...  MethodMissing exception for Date.parse?  Eeek...1.5.0... that's a blast from the past ;-)

Comment: Darnit... `Date.parse` came in version 1.5.7 :-(

Comment: I checked into the feasibility of just getting the src for Groovy's newer Date features, but it appears they just build a facade (somewhere) around `java.util.Date` and I haven't tracked down the location yet.

Comment: @avgvstvs the code to get the DAY_OF_MONTH [is here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DateGroovyMethods.java#L33), and the `parse` method [is here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DateGroovyMethods.java#L33)...  I'll try and quickly come up with a Groovy 1.5.0 friendly method...

Comment: @avgvstvs How's that?  Edited my answer :-)

Comment: This is the most flexible solution overall, and it will be the one I use.  Thank you!

Comment: Question, the call `get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH )` doesn't seem to reference the variable `time`--some things in Groovy seem to work by magic.  Can you explain how Groovy knows the correct context here?

Comment: @avgvstvs `Calendar.instance.with` [sets the default scope](http://bit.ly/LOZXA4) to be that of a new `Calendar` instance. So `time = ...` is actually calling [`setTime` on the Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29), then `get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH )` is calling [get on this same Calendar instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29).  I should have written it out long-hand I guess to explain it better, but Groovy makes you type less, the more you use it ;-)

Comment: @avgvstvs Hope that explains it ok!  Let me know if not, and I'll edit my answer to show the long version ;-)

Comment: No, I get it just fine,  I just needed Oz to lift the curtain!  ;-)

Comment: @avgvstvs haha, there's no place like home :-) good luck with the project :-)

Answer (score 2):

If its formatted the same always, I'd use the substring method of String to pull out what you want. REGEX has to be parsed every time you use it.

Answer (score 2):

The code is more meaningful if you use DateFormat, setDateFormat with the format of the string, then parse for the Date object. Performance wise, there may be more overhead than your methods.

However, I want to point out that:
If you can trust the input String, then you can use whatever you want to get the result.
If you cannot, then just use DateFormat to parse the date string.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you should opt for the solution which yields the most readable and maintainable code, so I would go for the `.split` approach as opposed to the Regular Expression approach.

Consider a few months down the line and the format of the date changes. This would mean that you would have to make slight changes to the regular expression. Although this might not be a daunting task, it might be something which is not as straightforward for someone who has had a limited exposure to regular expressions.

For this case, the `.split("//")` in this case is pretty intuitive so it is easier for people who do not have regular expression experience to understand and hence maintain.

Comment: If you're worrying that the date format could change, then the split method should be avoided as well.

Comment: @avgvstvs: The assumption is that the separators stay the same, but otherwise, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it with minimal resources, please consider using String#indexOf and String#substring. It is also important to note that doing a benchmark will help you making the right decision.

I think that using a regex is very concise in this matter and communicates that you are only interested in the middle part, the split version is harder to read, because you don't know how many elements split return, unless you encode it in a comment.

Neither the simple regex approach nor the split approach will give you a proper date validation. For that try to consider using the parse function of a DateFormat. Which will probably be the slowest of all.

Answer (score 1):

Noticing the java tag, isn't it feasible to call [DAY_OF_MONTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) to get the "day" part instead of regexing or splitting it out?